# type script : type of error in catch closure

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using **typescript** with **VueJS**

I have **type** error here

I did `type assertation` as you see

**but** error continue

```js
catch (err) {
  
   const  msg = (err as TypeError)?.response?.statusText
}
```

what should i **do** ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `catch (err: TypeError)` ?

Comment: @bassxzero typescript does not support that. The error in a catch block can only be  `unknown` or `any`.

Comment: @bassxzero , then we will have type error on response on : err.response

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can check if `err` really is a `TypeError` like:

```
catch (err) {

   if (err instanceof TypeError) {
  
       const  msg = err.response?.statusText

   }
   
}
```

More information:
`err` could be really anything, since you can throw whatever you like in javascript (which you probably should avoid):

```js
function foo() {
    try {
        throw 'this is not an error'; // don't do that!
    } catch (err) {

        if (err instanceof Error) {
            console.error('error', err);
        } else {
            console.log('log', err);
        }
    }
}

foo(); // log this is not an error
```